# Run a python script when connected to internet (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: linux

I have a simple python script `hello.py` and a `hello.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -c "from hello import hello; hello()"
```

(`hello.py` is in PYTHONPATH)

made it executeable and placed in the `if-up.d` directory. Being in the directory and running `./hello.sh` it works as it should. But disconnecting and re-connecting does not trigger the script.

Any idea?

Comment: Please show us the output of `ls -l /etc/network/if-up.d/hello.sh` ...

Comment: Also, when you say `hello.py is in PYTHONPATH` ... is it in root's PYTHONPATH or in yours?